# LEFT OUTER JOIN with INNER JOIN to Equal Total Rows

Tags: mysql, left-join, relational-database

I have a Producer and Product table. I'm trying to write 2 queries, Producers that have Products and Producers that don't have Products.

The rows returned from each Query should add up to the total rows in the Producer Table, but this is not the case with my code. The sum of both queries is 819 but there are only 766 rows in the Producer table. Where are the duplicates coming from?

What am I doing wrong with my JOINs?

```
PRODUCER TABLE
+------+--------+------+------+
| producerID  | producerName  |
+------+--------+------+------+
|  123        | Toys R Us     |
|  234        | GameStop      |
|  345        | Amazon        |
+------+--------+------+------+

PRODUCT TABLE
+------+--------+------+--------+------+
| productID | productName | producerID |
+------+--------+------+--------+------+
|  1        | Mega Man    |  123       |
|  2        | Lemmings    |  234       |
|  3        | Mario Kart  |  234       |
+------+--------+------+--------+------+


/*STORES CARRYING Products*/
/*This query returns 169*/
SELECT producerName, pt.producerID, productName
FROM Product pt 
INNER JOIN Producer pd ON pt.producerID = pd.producerID 

/*STORES NOT CARRYING Products*/
/*This query returns 650 */
SELECT producerName, pt.producerID, productName
FROM Producer pd
LEFT OUTER JOIN Product pt ON pt.producerID = pd.producerID
WHERE pt.producerID IS NULL

/*Count all rows returns 766*/
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Producer
```

Comment: In general, relying on the appearance of `IS NULL` from an `OUTER JOIN` is asking for trouble. Nulls are an abomination. Use a sub-query with `[NOT] IN`, per @CurtLH's answer; or with `[NOT] EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a Join, you could use a [Subquery](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/).

For example, this query would return all the producers that have a product.

```
SELECT *
FROM Producer
WHERE producerID IN (SELECT producerID FROM Products)
```

And this query would return all the producers that do not have a product.

```
SELECT *
FROM Producer
WHERE producerID NOT IN (SELECT producerID FROM Products)
```